# Department's "Employee of the Month" -- Fetched Property? How? Or something else?

Tags: swift, core-data, fetched-property

I have a Core Data database with Employees and Departments.  Each employee belongs to one department and each department has many employees.  So far, so good.  I want to add the ability to store, for each department, their current **Employee of the Month**, which would point to **one** Employee at a time.

When I do this as a *relationship*, I get the warning that the relationship should have an *inverse* relationship.  But the employee already belongs to the department, and it doesn't seem to make sense to create for each employee a relationship of "department where I'm employee of the month" which for all but one employee in each department, would be nil.  (Not trying to track a history of an employee's kudos in the database.)

It seems, from reading the high-level descriptions, like this is the sort of use where a **Fetched Property** would work well -- a '[weak, one-way relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1738991/7106170)', but most articles describing how to implement a Fetched Property (a) use Objective C code rather than Swift, and/or (b) go into ***far*** more complexity than it seems like this should need. The use case isn't about fetching something with a predicate, just assigning it.  All I want to do is:

```
thisDepartment.employeeOfTheMonth = thisEmployee
```

and then later

```
recognitionStr = thatDepartment.employeeOfTheMonth.name
```

Is there a better way to go about this?  Or is Fetched Properties the right approach?  And, if the latter, what is the simple, straightforward way to set up the `employeeOfTheMonth` relationship, in Swift?  Thanks!

Comment: Maybe not what your looking for but "Employee of the Month" doesn't really belong to Department but rather as a separate entity with relations to Department and Employee and a date attribute for the month of the reward.

Comment: Each department has their current Employee of the Month, and that's what I want stored for each department.  Not interested in tracking the history of who was the E-of-the-M last month, prior month, etc, just "who is IT right now, for (this) department."

Comment: Sure, just a comment. Create a relationship then, the inverse relationship might look awkward but it is mostly needed for Core Data and you don't need to use it in your code.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Core Data needs the inverse to work well. So one option is just create an inverse relationship on `Employee`. It's awkward, but you'll never use it in your code, so... it's not so bad?

But how I would do it (caveat: I've never used fetched properties): I would add an *attribute* on `Department` that'd be something `employeeOfTheMonthID`. Then I would write a property on the `Department` class like this:

```
var employeeOfTheMonth: Employee? {
  get {
    guard let id = employeeOfTheMonthID else { return nil }
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<Employee>(...)
    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "employeeID == %@", argumentArray: [id])
    fetchRequest.fetchLimit = 1
    return (try? managedObjectContext?.fetch(fetchRequest))?.first
  }
  set {
    employeeOfTheMonthID = newValue?.employeeID
  }
}
```